# Conversion rate in SQL Server (subquery)

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a sales data where I have column called stages which has three categories won, lost and open.

I want to write a query for conversion rate. The amount got from  the stage won divide by amount got won+lost for one sales rep. The sales rep got total of 50 at stages won and 120(stages won and lost). So my query should execute 50/120. Please the image link for data.

```
select 
    id, sum(sales) 
from 
    df 
where 
    id = '123' 
    and stage ='won'
group by 
    id 
having 
    sum(sales) / (select sum(sales) 
                  from df 
                  where stage = 'Won' OR stage = 'Lost')
```

I'm getting an error from this query. Not sure how to get the answer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukv4a.jpg)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Can you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: In the question please. Also add the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
select id,
    sum(case when stage = 'won' then sales end) * 1.0 / sum(sales)
from your_table
where stage in ('won', 'lost')
group by id;
```

If the denomintor can be 0, use `NULLIF` to avoid divide by zero error and return null instead.

```
select id,
    sum(case when stage = 'won' then sales end) * 1.0 / nullif(sum(sales), 0)
from your_table
where stage in ('won', 'lost')
group by id;
```

Comment: @Nirmal - Please **[EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43967593/edit)** your question and add **sample data and expected results**.